# Was there a city called "Margorin" or "Margorum" in Prussia in 1885?

Tags: geography, prussia

According to genealogical research, my great-grandfather emigrated on the SS Coriolan in 1869 whose port of exit was Bremen. Records indicate that my great-grandfather was from the city of Margorin or Margorum, but I am unable to read the handwriting and unable to locate any city with a similar spelling in Prussia. Did such a city exist in Prussia at that time?

Comment: Can you post an image of the document?

Comment: 1885 or 1869? The title differs from the question body.

Answer (score 6):

[Passagierlisten.de](http://passagierlisten.de/) is a register of passenger list from the port in Bremen. While it does not have passenger lists from before 1900 (they were lost in WW2) it does feature a list of towns of origin, which amongst all others also includes [Margonin](http://212.227.236.244/auswanderung/passregister/ortslist.php?b=M&lang=de).

One you know this exists one can simply look in up the Wikipedia entry for [Margonin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margonin).

> Margonin [marˈɡɔɲin] is a town in Chodzież County, Greater Poland
> Voivodeship, Poland, with 2,941 inhabitants (2004). [...]
>
> The area was included in the First Partition of Poland, at which time
> the area fell to Prussia, and was then part of the Grand Duchy of
> Posen until 1848, except for the Napoleonic period of the Duchy of
> Warsaw (1807 to 1815), and then part of the Prussian province of Posen
> until 1918

Since Posen used to be in the east of Prussia that's likely to be the one, and it does still exist as a small polish city of some 3000 people.

Answer (score 2):

I found a [list of cities and towns in East Prussia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_towns_in_East_Prussia). The closest I could find to your two examples is "Mohrungen", which now apparently is known as [Morąg, Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mor%C4%85g).

However, East Prussia in 1945 is pretty different from Prussia in 1869, and Morag is pretty far from Bremen. In 1869, I believe all the territory colored blue, green, and light blue, could be technically considered "Prussia".

[image]

Comment: _Morag is pretty far from Bremen_ - Bremen (or more exactly Bremerhaven) and Hamburg would have been port of departure for basically anybody who emigrated from Europe to the New World at the time (to the great chargrin of later German rulers there is a certain dearth of ports with access to the open sea in the area). So that by itself would not exclude Mohringen

Comment: @EikePierstorff. If he was really from EAST Prussia he would have sailed from Königsburg or Danzig and not travelled all the way to Bremen. But, as I said, we really need to see the document.

Comment: @fdb Really? I'm not an expert, but I am not aware of emigration significant traffic from Königsberg or Danzig to the US, whereas Hamburg and Bremen processed some 13 mio emigrants between 1850 and 1930. If you look at passagierliste.de (the passenger lists from the Bremer City Archives, unfortunately the pre-1900 stuff was mostly lost  in WW2) you will see that even people from Königsberg directly emigrated via Bremen. But I agree that we would need to see the document - it's probably written in some variant of Fraktur, so it would be easy to misread certain letters.